# How to deal with fact table data that needs to be version controlled?

Tags: mysql, database-design, facttable, slowly-changing-dimension, version-control

I have the following simplified `sport_match` 'fact' table:

| match_id | tournament_id | player_id_p1 | player_id_p2 | p1_final_score | p2_final_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 |

The table is updated from an API that issues `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` SQL instructions via text files.

Occasionally there is a mistake in the scores and because I need to be able to run historical analyses from a specific point in time I need to capture the incorrect entry and the correct entry. For this reason I started to look at adopting a [Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row) and translating all the API instructions to `INSERT`. This would give me a table that looked like this:

| match_key | match_id | tournament_id | player_id_p1 | player_id_p2 | p1_final_score | p2_final_score | start_date | current_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 01/01/2000 00:00 | Y |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 02/01/2000 00:00 | Y |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 03/01/2000 00:00 | Y |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 04/01/2000 00:00 | N |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 04/01/2000 00:01 | Y |

However, I realised I was applying a 'dimension' principle to a 'fact' table.

Is this a viable approach or should I be looking at a different design?

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case; a little more googling gave me an [answer](http://brentgreenwood.blogspot.com/2011/12/slowly-changing-facts.html). Just in case the link ever breaks:

> So the way the solution works is that the fact table changes are
> simply treated like SCD type 2 changes that are commonly used with
> dimension processing. Add a Start and End Effective Date to each row
> to track the versions and allow point-in-time analysis. Also, in
> addition to what the Kimball model shows, I ended up using a
> currentFlag to make it easier for my client to filter out history
> (similar to how one would do on a dimension with history).
>
> With historical fact changes handled, let's focus on dimension
> changes.  In this case, the complication is that typically an SCD2
> change in a dimension spawns a new surrogate key for the dimension
> row.  And that key would need to be embedded in the fact table as a
> foreign key.  But what if the fact row didn't have a change?  You
> would need to create a new fact row with the new dimension surrogate
> key to keep the relationship intact.  Obviously, that would cause some
> serious growth in your fact table.  Row splits without much benefit.
>
> Fortunately, that approach isn't necessary.  The Kimball article lays
> out a dimension design where you keep the same surrogate key on each
> Type 2 dimension row, but manage the End Dates appropriately.
> Equivalent of assigning a DW surrogate key for the master entity (not
> each SCD2 row) to replace the business key. Then use that master key,
> in combination with the End Effective Date, to define a unique row (or
> PK on the table).  The reality with this approach is that you have a
> many-to-many between the fact table and the dimension on the dimension
> master key.  So when querying the dimension and fact table, you must
> force your query/anlaysis tools to choose a "version" or as-of date
> that falls between the dimension effective dates.  This allows you to
> avoid bringing back all combinations and resulting in overstated
> measurements. Makes the ETL and the presentation layer a bit more
> challenging, but avoids the fact table headaches that would have
> resulted from the row splitting approach.